# link_to file name with a thumbnail of file type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thumbnails, file-type

Ruby on Rails 3.2, I have a table that shows files by basename. I would like to show a thumbnail next to the name of the file type. So if its a pdf file I would show a little image indicating its a pdf file. The files show the file type but I would like an image also to make it easier to pick out.

This is my loop for my table showing the file names only. How would I add a image based on the file type?

```
<tbody>
  <% @files.each do |file| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to File.basename(file).upcase, file[/\/.*/] %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

This is one example of a file being viewed.

```
ENGLISH_FACTSHEET2013_V3.PDF
```

I am hoping there is a gem or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach could be a `helper` that checks for the file extension with some regex or some simple string comparison, then creates a `image_tag` based on the type:

```
def extension_image(file_name)
  if file_name.upcase.include?('.PDF')
    image_tag 'pdf.png'
  elsif file_name.upcase.include?('.JPG')
    ...
  ...
end
```

Then on your view:

```
<td>
  <%= extension_image(File.basename(file)) %>
  <%= link_to File.basename(file).upcase, file[/\/.*/] %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
file.content_type
```

It should return something like "application/pdf"